# Open Cart Load Module in Custom HTML

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Open Cart for my website, on the home page, i would like to add a custom html and inside that custom html i would like to display a carousel and a featured product list side by side. Can this be done?

here is the sample layout
http://majalah.thegoodwords.com.my/image/opencart-custom-section.jpg

Comment: I've never used open cart, but I can answer _Can this be done?_. The answer is **yes**. Try to investigate your problem further and write a specific question. If your next question is _How do I do it?_, that's generally considered too broad for SO.

Comment: Hi Jon, i did go in further and found the solution. i change the featured.tpl file and edit it as how i want it to look. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default opencart doesn't have a plugin mechanism, what you can do is

"Modify the existing opencart code" directly or 
using vqmod https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki